# Restangular and query params not working

Tags: json, angularjs, restangular

I'm using Restangular in my Ionic application.
I'm trying to add Infinite scrolling, and I must call with Restangular

http://www.example.it/api/v1/contents.json?page=2

I'm looking the Restangular documentation ([here](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)) and I try with

```
Restangular.all("contents").getList("contents", {page: 2})
```

but the api call Restangular generate is

```
http://www.example.it/api/v1/contents.json?0=c&1=o&2=n&3=t&4=e&5=n&6=t&7=s
```

Any idea?

Comment: Post more code. Are you using the most recent version of Restangular? Also note that the documentation says it does not support AngularJS 1.3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
Restangular.all("contents").getList({"page": 2})
```